# What is the colon (:) expression in verilog structure assignment pattern?

Tags: structure, system-verilog

For example,

```
typedef struct packed {
  logic foo_1;
  logic foo_2;
} my_type

my_type foo_out;

assign foo_out = ‘{
  foo_1 : sig_1,
  foo_2 : sig_2
};
```

It looks like that, just same as

```
assign foo_out = {sig_1, sig_2};
```

I can’t find any structure assignment pattern using colon (:) in LRM.
Anybody please leave comment where this kind of expression is describled.

Comment: this is a syntax introduced in **system verilog**. It does not exist in regular verilog. So, look in the correct lrm.

Answer (score 1):

This is a SystemVerilog expression, which isn't part of plain Verilog so you won't find it if you're searching in the Verilog LRM.

From the SystemVerilog LRM:

> It can sometimes be useful to set structure members to a value without having to keep track of how many
>   members there are, or what the names are. This can be done with the default keyword:
>
> ```
> initial s1 = {default:2}; // sets x and y to 2
> ```
>
> The {member:value} or {data_type: default_value} syntax can also be used:
>
> ```
> ab abkey[1:0] = {{a:1, b:1.0}, {int:2, shortreal:2.0}};
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The last statement you wrote is not an assignment pattern; it is a concatenation. If `sig_1` and `sig_2` are not single bit variables you have a problem. The `'` in front of the `{}`'s is critical.

Section 10.9.2 Structure assignment patterns of the IEEE 1800-2017 LRM explains that

```
assign foo_out = '{sig_1, sig_2};
```

is a positional structure element assignment pattern where the first argument gets assigned to the first element, the second argument gets assigned to the second element, and so on. Each argument gets truncated or padded too match each element.

The other form with the `:` gets matched by name instead of position.

```
assign foo_out = '{foo_2:sig_2, foo_1:sig_1};
```